# Как отправить / получить структуру в boost :: asio

Tags: c++, сеть, boost, serializedobject

Я собирался отправить структуру с клиента на сервер, используя `boost :: asio :: async_write_some`, в этом случае `boost :: serialization` приходит на помощь:

```
    //boost::serialization
struct blank
{
    int m_id;
    std::string m_message;

    template<typename archive>
    void serialize(archive& ar, const short version)
    {
        ar & m_id;
        ar & m_message;
    }
};

blank info;

info.m_id = 1;
info.m_name = "Rasul";

std::stringstream ss;
boost::archive::binary_oarchive out_archive(ss);

out_archive << info;
```

Kак я могу отправить / получить `out_archive`, используя `boost :: asio` асинхронно? Если у вас есть другие идеи?

Answer (score 0):

У `std::stringstream`, в который вы сериализуете свою структуру, есть метод `str`, позволяющий получить содержимое потока в виде строки, её уже можно преобразовать в бинарный буфер при помощи `asio::buffer`, который можно отправлять асинхронно. Только нужно помнить, что буфер на самом деле хранит ссылку на исходную строку, и нужно не допустить её удаления раньше времени.

С точки зрения производительности это не оптимальный подход, т.к. содержимое потока копируется в строку, но boost::serialisation в любом случае не славится производительностью. Можно попытаться немного оптимизировать и влезть во внутренность потока при помощи `rdbuf`, но тут уже нужно разбираться с внутренним устройством стандартных потоков. Проще взять другую библиотеку сериализации без использования потоков - в конечном счете вам нужно получить просто массив байт.